# How to set a global constant from a function Obj C

Tags: objective-c, global-variables, constants

I need to set a global const at runtime. As far as I understand they are set at compile time, however I'm using a global const as a url string thats referenced throughout the app. Depending on a option selected before the user logs in, I need the url string to change. This will only happen at run time before a user has logged in (for testing purposes)

I know an alternative is to just use a global variable (not constant) but I feel like thats not the best practice.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can save the url in NSUserDefaults Class of Objective-C and can change the url once user logged in.

Answer (score 0):

A constant in Objective-C has a very specific meaning - it's something known at compile time. If you need to set a value at runtime, you need a read-only property or a function returning the value.

If you decide to take a read-only property route, make a global singleton object, and put the desired property on it. Give the property read-only access, and use it throughout your program.

If you decide to use a global function, you can do it like this:

```
// This goes in the header
extern const char *urlString();

// This goes into the implementation file
static char *urlStringVal = NULL;
const char *urlString() {
    return urlStringVal;
}
```

Any function in the same implementation file as `urlString` has writing access to `urlStringVal`, and can change it as needed.

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight, great info. Will try both these out